# Matplotlib plots turn out blank even having values

Tags: python, machine-learning, analytics

I am new to analytics,python and machine learning and I am working on Time forecasting. Using the following code I am getting the value for train and test data but the graph is plotted blank.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statsmodels.tsa.api as ExponentialSmoothing
#Importing data
df = pd.read_csv('international-airline-passengers - Copy.csv')
#Printing head
print(df.head())
#Printing tail
print(df.tail())
df = pd.read_csv('international-airline-passengers - Copy.csv', nrows = 11856)
#Creating train and test set 
#Index 10392 marks the end of October 2013 
train=df[0:20]
test=df[20:]
#Aggregating the dataset at daily level
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Month,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') 
df.index = df.Timestamp 
df = df.resample('D').mean()
train.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(train.Month,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
print('1')
print(train.Timestamp)
train.index = train.Timestamp 
train = train.resample('D').mean() 
test.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(test.Month,format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M') 
test.index = test.Timestamp 
test = test.resample('D').mean()
train.Count.plot(figsize=(15,8), title= 'Result', fontsize=14)
test.Count.plot(figsize=(15,8), title= 'Result', fontsize=14)
plt.show()
```

Not able to understand the reason for getting the graph blank even when train and test data is having value.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the issue here. The thing is you are using *train.Count.plot* here, while the value of **"plt"** is still empty.If you go through the documentation of matplotlib(link down below), you will find that you need to store some value in plt first and here since plt is empty, it is giving back empty plot.
Basically you are not plotting anything and just showing up the blank plot.

Eg: plt.subplots(values) or plt.scatter(values), or any of its function depending on requirements.Hope this helps.

https://matplotlib.org/

Comment: Thanks for identifying the issue. But I am not sure how to plot that train and test values in plt. It will be very helpful if you will help with this issue.

Comment: @shivanijoshi send me the link to dataset, so that i can process further

Comment: Dataset consist of month and count as columns. For ex: Month
: 5/22/2018 23:56
Count: 4

Comment: Is this data just the dd/mm/yyyy time?

Comment: Yes. It is dd/mm/yyyy time

Comment: So does your data contains just the complete date, time and count, and you wish to plot the bar plot of the count column. Is that it
If i understand correctly, you can simply use the following: plt.bar(train["column_name"])
plt.show()

Comment: No. I want date on X-axis and Count on Y-Axis. To get the trend of count over time

Comment: https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-finance-part-yahoo-finance-api-pandas-matplotlib/. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Nisarg.Bhatt/Documents/data.csv", engine="python")

train=data.groupby(["versionCreated"])["Polarity Score"].mean()
table=hv.Table(train)
print(table)
bar=hv.Bars(table).opts(plot=dict(width=1500))
renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')
app = renderer.app(bar)
print(app)

from bokeh.server.server import Server
server = Server({'/': app}, port=0)
server.start()
server.show("/")
```

This is done by using Holoviews, it is used for visualisation purpose.If you are using for a professional application, you should definitely try this. Here the **versionCreated** is date and **Polarity** is similar to count. Try this

OR, if you want to stick to matplotlib try this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,9))

ax.plot(msft.index, msft, label='MSFT')
ax.plot(short_rolling_msft.index, short_rolling_msft, label='20 days rolling')
ax.plot(long_rolling_msft.index, long_rolling_msft, label='100 days rolling')

ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Adjusted closing price ($)')
ax.legend()
```

Also this can be used, if you want to stick with matplotlib

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I tried your motplotlib code. It is still showing a blank graph with my data.

Comment: Send me the entire matplotlib script at: nisargbhatt1998@gmail.com